# Backpropagation for neural network

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement a simple neural network. 
I know there is a lot of library already available out there, that is not the point.

My network has only 3 layers:
one input layer
one hidden layer
one output layer

The output layer has 8 neuron representing each a different class.

I've understand how to implement the feedfoward algorythm but i'm really struggling for the backpropagation one.

here is what i've come up with so far :

```
private void backPropagation(List<List<Input>> trainingData)
{
    List<Input> trainingSet = new ArrayList<Input>();
    for (int row = 0; row < trainingData.size(); row++) {           
        trainingSet = trainingData.get(row);
        //we start by getting the output of the network
        List<Double> outputs = feedFoward(trainingSet); 

        //Im using the Iris dataset, so here the desiredOutput is
        //the species where 
        // 1 : setosa
        // 2 : versicolor
        // 3 : virginica
        double desiredOutput = getDesiredOutputFromTrainingSet(trainingSet);    
        //We are getting the output neuron that fired the highest result
        //like if we have
        //Ouput layer :
        //Neuron 1 --> 0.001221513
        //Neuron 2 --> 0.990516510
        //Neuron 3 --> 0.452221000
        //so the network predicted that the trainingData correspond to (2) versicolor
        double highestOutput = Collections.max(outputs);
        //What our neuron should aim for
        double target = 0;

        List<Double> deltaOutputLayer = new ArrayList<Double>();
        List<List<Double>> newWeightsOutputLayer = new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
        for (int j = 0; j < outputs.size(); j++) {  
            double out = outputs.get(j);
            //Important to do j + 1 because the species classes start at 1 (1 : setosa, 2: versicolor, 3:virginica)
            if(out == highestOutput && (j + 1) == desiredOutput)
                target = 0.99; //1
            else
                target = 0.01; //0

            //chain rule
            double delta = (out - target) * LogisticFonction.sigmoidPrime(out);
            deltaOutputLayer.add(delta);


            //get the new weigth value from delta and neta
            List<Double> newWeights = new ArrayList<Double>();
            for (int weightIndex = 0; weightIndex < _outputLayer.get(j).get_weigths().size(); weightIndex++) {
                double gradient = delta * _outputsAfterActivationHiddenLayer.get(weightIndex);
                double newWeight = _outputLayer.get(j).get_weigths().get(weightIndex) - (_learningRate * gradient);
                newWeights.add(newWeight);
            }
            newWeightsOutputLayer.add(newWeights);  
        }

        //hidden layer
        double totalError = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _neuronsHiddenLayer.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < deltaOutputLayer.size(); j++) {
                double wi = _outputLayer.get(j).get_weigths().get(i);
                double delta = deltaOutputLayer.get(j);
                double partialError = wi * delta;
                totalError += partialError;
            }

            double z = _outputsAfterActivationHiddenLayer.get(i);
            double errorNeuron = LogisticFonction.sigmoidPrime(z);

            List<Double> newWeightsHiddenLayer = new ArrayList<Double>();

            for (int k = 0; k < _neuronsHiddenLayer.get(i).get_weigths().size(); k++) {
                double in = _neuronsHiddenLayer.get(i).get_inputs().get(k);
                double gradient =  totalError * errorNeuron * in;
                double oldWeigth = _neuronsHiddenLayer.get(i).get_weigths().get(k);
                double newWeigth = oldWeigth - (_learningRate * gradient);
                _neuronsHiddenLayer.get(i).get_weigths().set(k, newWeigth);
                newWeightsHiddenLayer.add(newWeigth);
            }
        }


        //then update the weigth of the output layer with the new values.
        for (int i = 0; i < newWeightsOutputLayer.size(); i++) {
            List<Double> newWeigths = newWeightsOutputLayer.get(i);
            _outputLayer.get(i).set_weigths(newWeigths);
        }
    }   
}
```

I've try testing with the Iris dataset : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set

but my result are very inconsistant leading me to belive there is a bug in my backpropagation algorythm.

If anyone can see some major flaw tell me please!

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code:

```
if(out == highestOutput && (j + 1) == desiredOutput)
     target = 0.99; //1
else
     target = 0.01; //0
```

The target output of the neuron is `0.99` when the condition `(out == highestOutput && (j + 1) == desiredOutput)`. It means that you would only expect the output of the neuron to be `0.99` when the feedforward outputs the same neuron as the training example. This is incorrect.

The condition on that part of the code should've been only `(j + 1) == desiredOutput`. Remove `out == highestOutput` condition. The target output should be `0.99` for the desiredOutput neuron no matter whether the feedforward results in that neuron or not. So this is the corrected code:

```
if((j + 1) == desiredOutput)
     target = 0.99; //1
else
     target = 0.01; //0
```